# Pascal problem using dispose and later asigning NILL to that pointer. This problem only occurs when I use a for x in z

Tags: pointers, turbo-pascal

```
procedure freeMem (var v: tTabla; i: integer);
var
p : tPEntero;
begin
for p in v do
    if p^ < i then
        begin
        dispose(p);
        p := NIL;
        end;
writeln('Memory disposed.');
end;
```

I have an array of 4 pointers that point to this integers:

[1, 2, 3, 4]

In the main program I call the procedure `freeMem(table, 2);` meaning that the expected result when I call the method `writeTable(table);` should be:

[NIL, 2, 3, 4]

But the result obtained is:

[12800, 2, 3, 4]

Basically a random value where I disposed the pointer.

If I modify the procedure `freeMem(v, i)` and don't use a `for -- in -- do` it works somehow, I wanna know why it doesn't work the other way

```
procedure freeMem (var v: tTabla; i: integer);
var
indice: integer;
begin
for indice:=1 to MAX do
    if v[indice]^ < i then
        begin
        dispose(v[indice]);
        v[indice] := NIL;
        end;
writeln('Memory disposed.');
end;
```

Comment: for..in is not Turbo Pascal syntax.